# Content files auto included by Nuget

Tags: c#, nuget

The structure of my folder & source codes.

```
Areas/**/*.cshtml
Views/**/*.cshtml
```

And those cshtml files were compiled into dlls by generators. So that it does not need to be included into nuget packages. (Only the dll is needed)
So the Nuspec file will be like this.

```
<files>
</files>
```

Now I want to include additional dlls into Nuget packages.
So i added the following the Nuspec file

```
<files>
<file src="bin\Release\**\xxxxx.dll" target="lib\net451" />
</files>
```

But this will bring the *.cshtml files into nuget packages.
Is there any way that i could exclude those files?
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to @rohit21agrawal and @jainaashish.
I create an issue in github
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6265

> If you are packing your csproj with a .nuspec next to it, then the content files from your project will be added if one of the condition is met:
>
> 1. There is no nuspec file
> 2. There is a nuspec file but no files node.
> 3. There is a nuspec file with non-empty files node.
>
> The only way to prevent content files from your project to be added into the package is to specify an empty files node.